# MySQL stored procedure if statement not working

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have the following stored procedure in MySQL

```
CREATE DEFINER=`test_db`@`%` PROCEDURE `ADD_ATTENDANCE`(IN `programID` INT, IN `clientID` INT, IN `insDate` DATETIME, IN `updDate` DATETIME, IN `insUser` INT, IN `updUser` INT, IN `lessonDate` DATE, IN `lessonTime` TIME)
LANGUAGE SQL
NOT DETERMINISTIC
CONTAINS SQL
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
COMMENT 'Add attedance to my calendar'

BEGIN
    DECLARE max_sub, availability INT;
    DECLARE cursor_max_sub CURSOR FOR SELECT max_sub FROM app_lesson WHERE id = programID;
    DECLARE cursor_availability CURSOR FOR SELECT count(*) FROM attendance WHERE program_id = programID AND lesson_date = lessonDate AND lesson_time = lessonTime;
    OPEN cursor_max_sub;
    OPEN cursor_availability;

    read_loop: LOOP
        FETCH cursor_max_sub INTO max_sub;
        FETCH cursor_availability INTO availability;
        IF (availability < max_sub) THEN
            insert into attendance (program_id, client_id, ins_date, upd_date, ins_user, upd_user, lesson_date, lesson_time) 
            values (programID, clientID, insDate, updDate, insUser, updUser, lessonDate, lessonTime);
            LEAVE read_loop;
        ELSE
            insert into attendance_hold (program_id, client_id, ins_date, upd_date, ins_user, upd_user, lesson_date, lesson_time) 
            values (programID, clientID, insDate, updDate, insUser, updUser, lessonDate, lessonTime);
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE cursor_max_sub;
    CLOSE cursor_availability;
END;
```

Even though the `cursor_max_sub` is equal to 6 and the `cursor_availability` is equal to 4 my procedure always executes the else insert statement. Can you please help me out?

Thanks!!!

Comment: are your sure about your if condition?

Comment: How and when do you exit the loop? Compare yours with the example here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cursors.html. I'd add some code for the case that the cursors don't return any values ...

Comment: Hello. Thanks Trinimon for your comment. For some reason the max_sub cursor returns NULL even the SQL returns 6

Comment: Are id = programID parameters?Show us the whole procedure

Comment: I just edit my post and add the full statement

Answer (score 0):

OK that was tricky... For some reason when i change the `max_sub` variable into `maxNumberOfSubscription` everything worked perfectly... Is `max_sub` some kind of reserved key word for MySQL or there was a complication because my variable had the same name with the returned field of select statement?